# Get a new df with the mean values of other dfs

Tags: pandas

I have 1 list composed of unknown number  of dfs:

The dfs have same dimensions with same column names and same column values in the same order:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(data=np.transpose([[1,2,3,4],[2,4,6,8]]),index=['A','B','C','D'],columns=['x','y'])
df2=pd.DataFrame(data=np.transpose([[3,3,3,3],[4,4,4,4]]),index=['A','B','C','D'],columns=['x','y'])
```

I would like to group the values of the n dfs into a new df with the values being the mean of the values of the n dfs

The ouput

```
df2=pd.DataFrame(data=np.transpose([[2,2.5,3,3.5],[3,4,5,6]]),index=['A','B','C','D'],columns=['x','y'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with `mean` per index values:

```
print (pd.concat([df1, df2]).mean(level=0))
     x    y
A  2.0  3.0
B  2.5  4.0
C  3.0  5.0
D  3.5  6.0
```

Answer (score 1):

First concatenate the dataframes, reset the index to use it as groupby-keys and then calculate the mean over all columns.

```
pd.concat([df1, df2]).reset_index().groupby('index').mean()
```

Output

```
      x       y
index       
A     2.0   3.0
B     2.5   4.0
C     3.0   5.0
D     3.5   6.0
```